# MSVS linker adding data between static const strings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory, linker, win32-process

I was looking at the data section in the executable generated by the msvs 2008 linker and I'm seeing that it inserts some sort of markers between const static strings :

[image: excerpt from the executable]

I looked at a few other executables and I'm seeing the same pattern. Actual byte values are different though but still inserted inbetween the strings. 
 I looked at the generated map file and it doesn't look like a memory alignment measure (some addresses ending with 0xc, which would mean alignment to 4 but why adding so many padding zeroes in between) and even if it was, why would this value be added consistently? Some sort of guard sequence for the detection of memory corruption or some other reason I'm not aware of?
 Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure those are static strings? They look like RTTI data blocks to me, with the readable strings being the type names, which would suggest that the other bytes are more type information.

Comment: Ok, I think you are right. It's a bit tricky to find the exact lines in map file because of name mangling so I assumed these were static strings from std and boost internals. I don't know the details of RTTI implementation on MSVS, so assumed all this sort of data was coming from the actual code and not compiler adding this implicitly.
Another reason I thought this was from static as these values were following one of my const static arrays, hence I started the search.

Comment: So if anyone's interested in the internals of RTTI implementation in VC++, here's some info: http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23
In my case, these are indeed RTTI tables (see "?AU" and "?AV" prefixes added).